# Can bouncing bullets hit another tank?

Tags: world-of-tanks

In World of Tanks, bullets can be deflected by armor thickness. I'm wondering if it is possible for a bullet to bounce on a tank with suck an angle that it can go hit an other (or any destructible structure)?

Or maybe after a bounce the bullet just disappear in the air?

And if it can, *it is possible* that the bullet bounce to *the same* tank. Does it gives 2 succesfull hits for one single bullet to the one who shoot it? Does a bouncing bullet can destroy an other target and if yes, to who goes the kill?

As far as I remember I never saw something like that happening but I want to know if there is an ***non-null*** chance.

Thanks to anyone who can help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this is not possible. A bullet is able to hit the same tank twice (by bouncing of one point of armor, into another point). But it is not possible to bounce off and hit another tank.

Once a shell hits a vehicle it is "bound" that vehicle and can't hit anything else.

The only way to hit two targets with one shell is by using high explosive shells, this mostly happens with SPG shells landing right next to two targets, with the shockwave damaging both.

Source: [WOT battle mechanics richochet section](http://wiki.worldoftanks.com/Battle_Mechanics#Ricochet)

Comment: It should also be noted that ricochets can still cause damage to the tank that it came off. More on penetration can be viewed at: [World of Tanks. Explaining Mechanics - Penetration, Part 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wq5S8CrsUig)

Answer (score 1):

Since 9.3 it is possible to bounce and kill another tank, the one firing gets the kill.

Comment: Interesting. Source?

Comment: They do not mention this in the Release Notes for 9.3.